# lscpu shows incorrect number of cpus

Tags: cpu, lscpu

I've just checked cpu informations on one of ours servers and I am a little bit confused. Intel [says](https://ark.intel.com/products/120496/Intel-Xeon-Platinum-8180-Processor-38-5M-Cache-2-50-GHz-) that this model has 28 cores, whereas `lscpu` shows only 2. Am I missing something? Virtualization?

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 79
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8180 CPU @ 2.50GHz
Stepping:              0
CPU MHz:               2494.140
BogoMIPS:              4988.28
Hypervisor vendor:     VMware (<--- ??)
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              1024K
L3 cache:              39424K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
```

Comment: Your inside a VM with 2 CPU.

Answer (score 7):

You already highlighted the relevant info:

```
Hypervisor vendor:     VMware (<--- ??)
Virtualization type:   full
```

It is running under VMWare.

You probably ordered a virtual server with two cores, or more likely with one core with two threads.